# How can I execute a python script directly (without prefixing by the python command) from bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am just starting to use terminal for my programming needs. In a lot of Django tutorials I see people say, for example, I should type this in terminal:

```
manage.py runserver
```

However when I do this it says:

```
bash: manage.py: command not found
```

I get it to work when I do: `python manage.py runserver`, however I would like to understand why this works and the other method doesn't. I guess these are some very basic things but I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash(1)` will search your `PATH` environment variable to find programs to execute. `PATH` does not normally contain your "current working directory" (`.`) because that opens people up to trivial security problems:

```
cd /home/unsavory_character/
ls
```

If `unsavory_character` places an executable in `/home/unsavory_character/ls` that adds his or her `ssh(1)` key to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, you'd be in for a surprise -- he or she could log in as you without a password.

So systems these days don't add the current working directory to the `PATH`, because it is too unsafe.

The workaround:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

Of course, that assumes your current working directory is whichever directory contains the `manage.py` script. That might be a safe assumption. If you'd like to be able to execute it from anywhere in the filesystem, you can add the directory to your `PATH` by editing your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file. (If one of them already exists, pick that one. I seem to recall others with `PATH` problems on OS X found one or the the other file worked well, and the other one never got executed.)

(In my case, I have a bunch of self-written utilities in `~/bin/`, but yours might be elsewhere. Change the paths as appropriate.)

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 12):

It is because your `manage.py` is not an executable script.

First put this line at the top of `manage.py` (assuming your python is in `/usr/bin/python`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then make your script executable:

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

Then try to execute your script `./manage.py runserver`.

Read this link for more info: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable-on-unix.htm

Comment: thanks! could you maybe explain (or link to somewhere) about what #!/usr/bin/python really means so I can get a good understanding of this. I sometimes see windows tutorials where they change the PATH in somewhere in the windows settings, how can I do something like this on a Mac?

Comment: @Javaaaa: `#!` is pronounced [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` is the full path to python binary on your Mac. On Unix scripts this lines represents path to the binary executable that will interpret your script. Also there is a link in my answer, pls check that.

Answer (score 0):

manage.py needs to be executable. Try: `chmod +x manage.py`

Comment: I already tried that one, but it didn't work. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I've cooked together a small "script" to automate this: *(just copy whole text, and paste inside your active terminal.)*

```
tee -a ~/.profile <<EOF

if [ -d "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/bin" ] ; then
    PATH=/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/bin:$PATH
fi
EOF
```

Doesn't `django-admin.py` do the same? I think so, because I can find `manage.py` inside my `../bin` folder. And stated at the official documentation, they do the same. So I believe ;)

Also, have you obtained Django via `easy_install`? My script expect that you are using Snow Leopard with the system version (Python 2.6).